# Working with timezone in Django - Best Practices

Tags: django, timezone

I would like your opinion about the practices I am using to deal with timezone, as shown below. Is correct? Should I worry about any more details?

Each client/user of the system is located in a region with different time, so I put in the model the record that identifies the region:

In model:

```py
TIMEZONES = tuple(zip(pytz.all_timezones, pytz.all_timezones))
timezone = models.CharField (
    null = False,
    blank = False,
    max_length = 32,
    choices = TIMEZONES,
    default = 'UTC',
    verbose_name = "timezone",
    help_text = "Timezone"
)
```

When the user logs in, the settings.py TIME_ZONE variable changes according to the logged-in user's timezone:

At login:

```py
from django.conf import settings
settings.TIME_ZONE = timezone
```

When I do a cursor query, I timezone as it is in settings.py:

In the query:

```py
from django.conf import settings
timezone = settings.TIME_ZONE
query = "" "
    SET TIMEZONE = '{}';
    ...
"" ".format (timezone)
```

In templates, I enable timezone:

In the templates:

```
...
{% load tz%}
...
{% localtime on%}
...
{% endlocaltime%}
```

I hope I was clear in the presentation above. If you need more details, I can provide.

Thanks for sharing your experiences.

Comment: The settings module is not meant to be used dynamically like that. The way to dynamically set the current time zone is to use `activate()`, as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone). I'm not sure what you mean by a "cursor query"; are you saying that you're using raw queries instead of Django's ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal would be to use middleware to determine the user's time zone and save it in the session.

> Django provides time zone selection functions. Use them to build the
>   time zone selection logic that makes sense for you.

this answer is short because the correct answer is in Django documentation

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone